# Prevent Django's JsonResponse to serialize my string

Tags: python, json, django

I have a JSON string that I compute from a Pandas dataframe

```
aggr.aggregated.to_json(orient='values')
```

I cannot directly provide `aggr.aggregated` to a standard Python JSON serializer because it would not follow the `orient='values'` rules and would do so differently.

I want to serve my own JSON string as a response from a Django view:

```
return JsonResponse(aggr.aggregated.to_json(orient='values'))
```

However, in the code above, Django tried to serialize my JSON string.

How can I use `JsonResponse` exclusively to set the Content-Type header to application/json but **not** to serialize a string that is already serialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no benefit in using `JsonResponse` if you don't want it to encode the JSON for you.

Just use `HttpResponse` and set the content-type header yourself:

```
return HttpResponse(
    aggr.aggregated.to_json(orient='values'), 
    content_type='application/json' 
)
```